# Import and store multiple Excel Files in multiple folders to SQL Server table using SQL Server Integration services

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have multiple Excel files (Ms. Excel 2019) in multiple folders that I want to import and store the data to SQL Server table. I want to build a data warehouse for Power BI dashboard and choose SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) in Visual Studio 2019 as ETL tools.

In Data Flow Task, I use Excel Source, set Output Error to Flat File destination, and write to OLE DB Destinations. The package run success, but only writes the flat file (`.csv`) to OLE DB.

[image: Data flow task for Excel files]

I also use For Each Loop, for looping multiple Excel through multiple folders

[image]

[image: Root folder in For each loop]

The data write to the SQL Server table but only 1 file from 1 folder that data successfully writes to OLE DB SQL server.

Is there any way to load other files either `.xlsx` file or `.csv` file write (prefer `.xlsx` file) to OLE DB and store to SQL Server table?

Comment: I use .xlsx, Ms. Excel 2019. the raw data in .xlsx. Thank you for pointing out

Comment: What's the actual problem? CSV files are text files with commas, not some kind of Excel format. They're loaded/exported using the Flat File source or destination. The Excel source on the other hand will handle both xls and xlsx. If you want to handle different file types, use a different loop container using a different pattern

Comment: In fact, you could use SQL Server's `bcp` or `BULK INSERT` to insert data from CSV or other text files into a staging table and process it afterwards. You don't have to use SSIS.

Comment: I use Flat File Destination in Excel Source error output, in my understanding (please correct me if I'm wrong), from redirect rows in SSIS Excel Source the data goes to flat file,  and to use the flat file destination I convert the .xlsx file to .csv. 

I am new in SSIS, and I'm exploring the Data Flow. I am happy if you can suggest the correct flow process. thank you

Comment: I use SSIS because in the future, the raw data will be expanded and the source file are from an external source. Is there any way to use other tools for ETL process?

Comment: Is "Flat File Destination 1" the CSV you are referencing or is it the unpictured output of the "OLE DB Destination" -> "Multicast"

Comment: Right, the CSV that I am referencing is the Flat File destination